# Why Telegram bot answerInlineQuery response Bad Request: STICKER_DOCUMENT_INVALID?

Tags: node.js, telegram

Trying to answer inline query with the sticker cause error 400 `Bad Request: STICKER_DOCUMENT_INVALID`.

My response looks like following

```
const sticker = {
  type: 'sticker',
  id: '0',
  sticker_file_id: 'file_id_obtained_from_upload_sticker_method'
};

ctx.telegram.answerInlineQuery(query.id, [sticker]);
```

In according to Telegram documentation [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultcachedsticker) and Telegraf documentation [here](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=answerinlinequery) everything seems to be right. In reality:

```
{
  code: 400,
  response: {
    ok: false,
    error_code: 400,
    description: 'Bad Request: STICKER_DOCUMENT_INVALID'
  },
  description: 'Bad Request: STICKER_DOCUMENT_INVALID',
  parameters: {},
  on: {
    method: 'answerInlineQuery',
    payload: { inline_query_id: '3997901566750938248', results: [Array] }
  }
}
```

No answer in google nor official documentation. Anyone has similar experience?

The sticker was previously successfully uploaded with method [uploadStickerFile](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=uploadstickerfile) provided url to request image file.

Comment: did you try with `sticker_id` that stored in sticker set in telegram, maybe it just answer with a sticker in telegram sticker set. As [uploadstickerfile in Telegram official doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#uploadstickerfile) "Use this method to upload a .PNG file with a sticker for later use in __createNewStickerSet__ and __addStickerToSet__ methods"

Comment: good point and seems logic. I tried two cases: A: 1. upload png -> recieve file_id. 2. answer directly without adding to set (unsuccessfull). 3. add to set by id (successfull). B: 1 upload png -> recieve file_id. 2. add sticker to set (successfull). 3 answer with sticker file id (unsuccessfull)...

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Upload png and add it to sticker just return you a `file_id` for png file. but you have to use `sendSticker` method or fetch the .WEBP in sticker set with `getStickerSet` method and get `file_unique_id`. Take a look at [Sticker in Telegram Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sticker) and difference between `file_id` and `file_unique_id`.

Comment: previously used method [uploadStickerFile](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=uploadstickerfile) got me `file_unique_id` as well, but when I use it in answerInlineQuery as `sticker_id` I got different but error `TelegramError: 400: Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. Wrong last symbol`